# Having trouble with releases in core graphics

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics, drawrect

I've just started with releasing in core graphics, so I might need a little help.

I have code which looks like this:

```
UIImage *buttonImage() {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();


    CGMutablePathRef outerPath;
    CGMutablePathRef midPath;
    CGMutablePathRef innerPath;
    CGMutablePathRef highlightPath;

//Some button stuff

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGContextRelease(context);

    return image;

}
```

That release line, I've put in. I'm getting an error with it though:

```
context_reclaim: invalid context
context_finalize: invalid context
```

Any thoughts as to where i should put the release in this instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to do `CGContextRelease(context)` if you have previously done a `CFRetain(context)` or a `CGContextRetain(context)`, or if you created the context yourself.  In your example, you are calling `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()`, which is handling the creation of the context for you, thus, calling `CGContextRelease()` yourself is over-releasing it.

You do need to balance the `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()` with either a:

```
CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace)
```

or a :

```
if (baseSpace) CFRelease(baseSpace)
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't own the context when using `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext`. Therefore you should not be releasing it. If you were to use `CGContextRetain()` then you would release. More information of this is available here:

[Memory Management Guide for Core Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/writerid/cfGetRule)

I highly suggest reading the `Memory Management` programming guide to get an understanding of how it works.